# How to Test WooCommerce in Staging Site

Tags: woocommerce, staging

I'm working on a client's WooCommerce site that I cloned to my own hosting account for a temporary staging site. The problem is when I attempt to Checkout, the URL tries to change to HTTPS and the browser throws an error.

How can I test the WooCommerce Checkout process while working in staging?

Comment: You should disable https (on staging) in the WC settings > Checkout (as you are on a subdomain or another domain). This happens. Then when you will update production, you will have to check this with https (but it should be all right).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the staging domain and make sure to completely pull the site data (site content & DB). BTW, I'm using Cloudways and it offers a one-click staging feature through which anyone can quickly push and pull the changes from staging to live & vice versa.

Comment: Check out this WordPress staging feature: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-staging-environment/